# Create Shortcut to the Latest File of a Folder in Windows

Tags: windows, file, directory, shortcut

Is there a way to creat shortcut always point to the latest (or the largest etc) of a folder in windows?

eg:
folder/file1   2012-01-01 xxx
folder/file2   2013-01-01 xxx

**folder/shortcut -> point to file2**

After editing file1:

folder/file1   2013-02-01 xxx
folder/file2   2013-01-01 xxx

**folder/shortcut -> point to file1**

Comment: No, there's not. Shortcuts are based on file name and location and a checksum. There's no way to create a shortcut that automatically changes to the latest file in a folder. (And this doesn't appear to be a programming question, BTW. It appears to be more of an operating system question, which is off-topic here.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a PowerShell script to open a file for you:

```
$dir = "C:\test_code"
$filter="*.txt"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
Invoke-Item $latest.fullname
```

Comment: I asked 7 years ago (and I forgot why I asked that), but thanks anyway.